# Why does Mesos offer resources?

Tags: mesos

What is the significance of the decision in Mesos for frameworks to be offered resources by Mesos? This seems to be mentioned a lot, but ultimately all of the logic is in the Mesos allocation module, so whether it's Mesos making and revoking offers, or frameworks asking for resources, is this just a semantic difference?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question:
The original [Mesos paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~alig/papers/mesos.pdf) states the following rationale:

```
The master implements fine-grained sharing across
frameworks using resource offers. Each resource offer
is a list of free resources on multiple slaves. The master
decides how many resources to offer to each framework
according to an organizational policy
```

Frameworks requesting would have the following consequences:

- Frameworks would have to be aware of resources in the cluster (e.g., does the cluster have GPUs)
- The logic of choosing the request (by a framework) which should be granted given fairness and existing free cluster resources seems more complex and less scalable than the current allocation mechanisms (Not having hard evidence here, but just a feeling after having touched the Mesos allocator code)

Maybe most interestingly the Mesos Scheduler interface includes a *requestResources(const std::vector& requests)* call. The default Mesos DRF allocator does not implement this call, but nothing prevents you from implementing an allocator which does so.

If you are interested in more details about cluster scheduler I can recommend this [blog post](https://medium.com/@ArmandGrillet/comparison-of-container-schedulers-c427f4f7421#.vw22vrk25) or the [Omega paper](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~mosharaf/Readings/Omega.pdf).

Update:
This MesosCon talk discusses some future extensions to more optimistic offers: http://schd.ws/hosted_files/mesosconna2016/51/MesosCon_2016_OptimisticOffer.pdf